# Synonym Safecracker with Channel Form

Tags: discussion

We currently have 2 tags, "safecracker" and "channel-form" which I think should be made a synonym as people who've only recently come across ExpressionEngine will probably know the feature as Channel Forms, but there's over 250 questions under the previous name of Safecracker they may otherwise not find.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I concur and have added this tag synonym to the system. Thank you for suggesting this!
https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms

Comment: Cheers Anna. Turns out I have tag synonym privileges now, coincidence!

Comment: You didn't have them before?

Comment: Nope, a question I answered yesterday tipped it over the edge. With great power...

Answer (score 1):

Agree with the synonym though currently the tag is displayed as safecracker. Since Channel Form is the name going forward, shouldn't this be the one that is displayed?

Comment: I feel this is quite important. If you look at the question I just posted http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/26153/setting-entry-status-with-channel-form

The tag says Safecracker, but the question relates to Channel Form. It's right to have a synonym but I think it should be the newer name that is used.